# Outputting transposed grouped pandas dataframe to CSV

Tags: python, csv, pandas, transpose, pandas-groupby

Relatively new to pandas - I have a dataframe with movie ID, user ID, rating, and date.  I've sorted by user ID and date and have the dataframe below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqSZ6.png

My desired output is a csv that has one row per user, with all the movies that user has rated sorted chronologically left to right. For example:

```
452 4 33 6581
56
121 69 98 802 555
.
.

master_sample.sort_values(['User ID','Date']).groupby('User ID')
```

However, after grouping by user ID I get a groupby object, which I'm unsure how to iterate over and output to csv.  I've tried pivot on the original df / iterating over the grouped df using get_group.

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
master_sample.sort_values('Date') \
             .groupby('User ID', as_index=False)['Movie ID'] \
             .apply(' '.join)
```

Comment: I like it a lot!